# UFO attacks in Past Continuous

Tags: reported-speech, past-continuous

The question is about the sentence used in the "story" about the UFO;) Please let me know which is grammatically ok:

1. When I was thinking then what might happen when they land, suddenly, to my great regret, they flew away.
2. When I was thinking then what might have happened when they landed, suddenly, to my great regret, they flew away.
3. When I was thinking then what might have happened when they would landed, suddenly, to my great regret, they flew away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 3 is flat-out improper English.

The first two work, however, I would replace

> "When I was thinking..."

with

> "*While* I was thinking..."

because it immediately conveys that you're describing how ***in the middle of your thinking***, the UFO suddenly flew away